# Cannot make calls from Skype for business mobile clients to Cisco

Tags: sip, wireshark, telephony, skype-for-business, cucm

I have a Skype for Business system currently deployed in my work area. Before that, we were using all the Cisco Clients and other telephony clients.

I am seeing a strange behavior, that is I am able to make calls from my Skype for Business mobile clients to my Cisco phones, but when I do reverse I cannot get the call established.

What is see is SIP status code 488 (in wire shark trace) - which is codec mismatch.

I see that an invite message from Cisco phone offers media via 0 and 101 codecs.
But still not able to get the call through.

Answer (score 0):

Check the path the INVITE is taking: outgoing the SfB will send the INVITE through the mediation server for audio trans-coding, but the Cisco may be attempting media bypass: trying to connect phones directly without going through the mediation server.

But this all depend on how the two are connected of-course and if a session border controller is involved or a hundred other little things.

You may want to refer to an official document: [Skype for Business  2015  using SIP trunk to Cisco  Unified Communications Manager Release 10.5.2 SU3](https://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en/us/solutions/collateral/enterprise/interoperability-portal/skyp-for-business.pdf)

That is over 100 pages on only one method of interconnecting the two ;)